# Mottie virtual keyboard with bootstrap theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, virtual-keyboard

I am using [Mottie virtual keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) with this [angular wrapper](https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard) around it, I want to use a bootstrap theme for my keyboard and I added it like this

```
VKI_CONFIG.css = {
                // input & preview
                input: 'form-control input-sm',
                // keyboard container
                container: 'center-block dropdown-menu', // jumbotron
                // default state
                buttonDefault: 'btn btn-default',
                // hovered button
                buttonHover: 'btn-primary',
                // Action keys (e.g. Accept, Cancel, Tab, etc);
                // this replaces "actionClass" option
                buttonAction: 'active',
                // used when disabling the decimal button {dec}
                // when a decimal exists in the input area
                buttonDisabled: 'disabled'
            };
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/1837/) you can find a live example of it, As I browsed demos and online examples of usage of this keyboard like [here](https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/docs/basic.html) and [here](https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard/blob/master/demo/index.html), In all of them keyboard gets resized when browser windows is resized, but I don't have that behavior at all, Am I missing something here? how can I make my keyboard to get resized when I resize my browser window (with bootstrap theme)?

Or in other words, how can I make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/1837/) keyboard to get resized on window resize?

Comment: Is it possible to use Mottie Virtual Keyboard in My Angular 5 Application. I tried. But i didn't get the output. Can You help me..?

Comment: I don't know angular 5, you can ask a separate question, The wrapper is pretty easy to write, But I suggest you to find a complete angular 5 ish solution because you depend on Jquery and jquery doesn't play well with Angular 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard doesn't have a css file specifically set up for Bootstrap, so the following media queries are needed to resize the keyboard (also see the [FAQ](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/FAQ#changesize)).

I don't know how accurate these settings are, but please feel free to adjust the font-size - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/4424/)

```
/* Media Queries */
/* 240 x 320 (small phone)  */
@media all and (max-width: 319px) {
    .ui-keyboard .ui-keyboard-button { font-size: 9px; }
    .ui-keyboard .ui-keyboard-input { font-size: 12px; }
}

/* 320 x 480 (iPhone)  */
@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    .ui-keyboard .ui-keyboard-button { font-size: 9px; }
    .ui-keyboard .ui-keyboard-input { font-size: 14px; }
}

/* 480 x 640 (small tablet) */
@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .ui-keyboard .ui-keyboard-button { font-size: 13px; }
    .ui-keyboard .ui-keyboard-input { font-size: 14px; }
}
```